# Using applescript to select a folder and use as variable

Tags: applescript, posix

I need to modify my current code to allow for the selection of a a folder. My current code is as follows and works to select a folder without issue:

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to folder POSIX file "/Users/Username/Desktop/Upload/Temp/HighRes/"
    set theFiles to files of sourceFolder
    set inputPath to "/Users/Username/Desktop/Upload/Temp/"
end tell
```

I have tried the following, but cannot determine the correct syntax to get to where I was in my original code

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    set inputPath to folder POSIX file (choose folder with prompt "Please choose folder to be processed")
    set sourceFolder to folder POSIX file (inputPath & "/HighRes")
    set theFiles to files of sourceFolder
end tell
```

The above processes but errors out and says that finder got an error  and cannot make alias "xyz" into type integer.

Comment: can someone enlighten me what this has to do with POSIX? I don't get it :)

Answer (score 1):

Please forget the POSIX dance. The Finder likes its native and `alias` specifiers.

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    -- inputPath is an alias specifier
    set inputPath to (choose folder with prompt "Please choose folder to be processed")
    -- sourceFolder is built as a Finder item specifier
    set sourceFolder to folder "HighRes" of inputPath
    set theFiles to files of sourceFolder
end tell
```

Even your first snippet can be written in a simpler way

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to folder "Upload:Temp:HighRes" of desktop
    set theFiles to files of sourceFolder
    set inputPath to folder "Upload:Temp" of desktop
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian for your help!!